# Aparecer botão após preenchimento de dois campos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho 2 campos de datas e irei usar essas datas em um select e gostaria que um botão "consultar" aparecesse somente quando os dois campos fossem preenchidos, segue o código atual:

```
     <form method="post" action="">

          Início do período:
          <input type="text" id="calendarioIni" name="dataInicio">*
          Fim do período:
          <input type="text" id="calendarioFim" name="dataFim">*
          <input type="submit" value="Consultar"/>**                                                                    
          <br><br><br>

          <?php if(isset($_POST['dataInicio']) && isset($_POST['dataFim']))
          {
               $dataIni = $_POST['dataInicio'];
               $dataFim = $_POST['dataFim'];
               echo $dataIni."<br>";//Teste para verificar o valor nas variáveis que recebem a data via POST
               echo $dataFim;
          } 
          ?>
          </form>

    <script>

       window.onload = function(){
   var dataIni = document.querySelector("#calendarioIni");
   var dataFim = document.querySelector("#calendarioFim");

   dataIni.addEventListener('input', checaVazio );
   dataFim.addEventListener('input', checaVazio );

   function checaVazio(){
      var botao = document.querySelector("form input[type='submit']");
      botao.style.display = dataIni.value && dataFim.value ? "inline" : "none";
   }
};

    var start = new Date(1997, 12, 01);
    var end = new Date(1998, 11, 31) ;
    var view = new Date(1997, 12, 01);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendarioIni').datepicker({
           endDate: end,
           startDate: start,
           startView: view

        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendarioFim').datepicker({
           endDate: end,
           startDate: start,
           startView: view

        });
    });

        </script>
```

*calendarioIni e calendarioFim são um datepicker.
**botão que gostaria que aparecesse somente após o preenchimento dos calendarios
Quais mudanças deveriam ocorrer para que o botão somente aparecesse com as datas preenchidas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Datepicker captura o evento de clicar em uma data em `onSelect:`. Desta forma, é preciso adicionar 2 `onSelect:` em cada função que aplica o calendários aos `inputs`, e chamar neles uma função que irá verificar se os campos estão vazios.

```js
var dataIni = document.querySelector("#calendarioIni");
var dataFim = document.querySelector("#calendarioFim");

function checaVazio(){
   var botao = document.querySelector("form input[type='submit']");
   botao.style.display = dataIni.value && dataFim.value ? "inline" : "none";
}

var start = new Date(1997, 12, 01);
    var end = new Date(1998, 11, 31) ;
    var view = new Date(1997, 12, 01);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendarioIni').datepicker({
           endDate: end,
           startDate: start,
           startView: view,
           onSelect: checaVazio

        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendarioFim').datepicker({
           endDate: end,
           startDate: start,
           startView: view,
           onSelect: checaVazio

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="">

  Início do período:
  <input type="text" id="calendarioIni" name="dataInicio">*
  Fim do período:
  <input type="text" id="calendarioFim" name="dataFim">*
  <input style="display: none;" type="submit" value="Consultar" />**                                                                    
  <br><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70170/discussion-between-v-avancini-and-dvd).

Answer (score 2):

Opa, boa tarde.
O que você pode fazer pra resolver isso é adicionar o display: none no style do botão e fazer uma verificação via jquery para ver se os inputs possuem algum conteúdo. Segue as modificações abaixo:

```
<input type="text" id="calendarioIni" onchange="ValidarPreenchimento()" name="dataInicio">*
Fim do período:
<input type="text" id="calendarioFim" onchange="ValidarPreenchimento()" name="dataFim">*
<input type="submit" value="Consultar" style="display:none" id="btnConsultar"/>**
```

adicionei um evento onchange em ambos os inputs de calendário e abaixo está a function que faz a validação

```
<script>
function ValidarPreenchimento(){
    var calendarioIni = $('#calendarioIni').val();
    var calendarioFim = $('#calendarioFim').val();

    if(calendarioIni != "" && calendarioFim != ""){
        $('#btnConsultar').show();
    }else{
        $('#btnConsultar').hide();
    }
}
```

Só não esquece de adicionar a referência ao jquery... 
Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: eu já tenho um script que define alguns atributos do calendario, ele não possui esse "type="", abro outro bloco script só pra esse método de validação ou posso colocar dentro do mesmo que já utilizo?

Comment: Eu costumo colocar em bloco separado

Comment: você poderia explicar melhor sobre a referência ao jquery?

Comment: <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
Eu estou usando um arquivo local antes desse bloco que mencionei na resposta, mas você pode ir no site da Jquery e baixar ou usar o endereço que eles disponibilzam

Comment: e esse bloco eu colocaria antes do botão?

Comment: Pode colocar no head

Comment: acontece que esse é um sistema que estou trabalhando, está cheio de pastas <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>, e tem esta referencia porém está no footer... testei o código que vc mandou e o botão não abriu

Comment: Se o jquery que está usando está no footer, esse bloco que te passei deve estar abaixo da referência do jquery.